# Mostrar colores en un dropdownlist

Tags: php, mysql, dropdownlist

Tengo una aplicación web, la cual tiene un formulario para el registro de nuevos usuarios; a cada usuario se le asigna un color único, tomado de la BD (MySQL).

Tengo una tabla de usuarios y una tabla de colores. Quiero que al momento de registrar un nuevo usuario en la opción de seleccionar un color, muestre los colores y no los códigos hexadecimales del color (así es que como está almacenados en la BD).

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
'<div class="form-row" style="justify-content: center !important;">'+
        '<div class="form-group col-md-11" style="margin-bottom:5px;">'+
            '<label for="ColorName" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;">Color</label>'+
            '<select class="form-control" name="ColorName">'+
            '<option value="">Seleccione</option>'+
            '<option value=""></option>'+
            <?php
            $Colors = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM cat_colores AS c WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id_color FROM user WHERE c.id != user.id_color)");
            $cat_colores = $Colors->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            for ($i=0; $i < count($cat_colores); $i++) {
                echo "'<option value=\"".$cat_colores[$i]['id']."\" style='width:40px;height:20px;background-color:".$cat_colores[$i]['has_color'].">".$cat_colores[$i]['has_color']."</option>'+";
            }
            ?>
        '</select></div>'+
    '<div>'
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu tabla de colores? Veo que tiene un `id` y un `has_color` (¿el valor hexadecimal?), pero sin saber cuáles son los campos de la tabla cat_colores, no te podemos dar una respuesta específica.

Comment: Solamente tiene dos campos: 'id' y 'has_color'

Comment: No comprendo, ¿qué es lo que quieres mostrar exactamente?¿Sólo el color sin el código?

Comment: Exactamente. He logrado mostrar los códigos de los colores, pero quiero que solamente muestre el color según el código

Comment: Quizás es que no me estoy enterando bien pero, ¿por que no simplemente no muestras el nombre del color en el option? Aunque eso puede darte problemas porque no todos los navegadores van a soportar de igual manera poner fondos en los `option` (pero sería el mismo problema que tendrías ahora).

Comment: Eso ya lo hice, pero necesito que muestre el color... ='(

Comment: ¿Qué navegador estás usando que no ves los colores de fondo? ¿Tienes alguna restricción de soporte?

Comment: Gracias, ya logré solucionarlo :)

Comment: ¡Genial! ¿Cómo lo hiciste al final?

Comment: echo "'<option value=\"".$cat_colores[$i]['id']."\" style=width:40px;height:20px;background-color:".$cat_colores[$i]['has_color']."></option>'+";

Cambie de lugar las \. Era lo que no dejaba que mostrara el color

Comment: Al final, sólo quitaste el nombre. Si funciona, genial. Deberías ponerlo en la sección de respuestas :)

Answer (score 0):

¡Solucionado!

```
'<div class="form-row" style="justify-content: center !important;">'+
        '<div class="form-group col-md-11" style="margin-bottom:5px;">'+
            '<label for="ColorName" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;">Color</label>'+
            '<select class="form-control" name="ColorName">'+
            '<option value="">Seleccione</option>'+
            '<option value=""></option>'+
            <?php
            $Colors = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM cat_colores AS c WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id_color FROM user WHERE c.id != user.id_color)");
            $cat_colores = $Colors->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            for ($i=0; $i < count($cat_colores); $i++) {
                echo "'<option value=\"".$cat_colores[$i]['id']."\" style=width:40px;height:20px;background-color:".$cat_colores[$i]['has_color']."></option>'+";
            }
            ?>
        '</select></div>'+
    '<div>'
```

Sólo le cambie de lugar las "\"